# auto login by requesting security token

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, security

**scenario:**

clientWebsite can only be accessed when a user has their security card inserted into PC.
ClientWebsite is outside of my control, as is everything to do w/ the security card.

I developed a js web app that requires username/password. The system requests a security token, and if provided credentials are valid, a token is returned and appended to all requests as a url parameter. Token is valid for 60 mins.

The sys admin of ClientWebsite wants to put a link to my js app on their secured site. If someone is able to view ClientWebsite, they are allowed to view my js app, and after following the link, should not have to login again.

I had sys admin insert a test link that would point to a page on our server and execute some js/jquery to retrieve http referrer, but it was always blank. Conclusion -- our client's browsers likely have referrer disabled, or ClientWebsite is configured in a way that disables sending referrer. Not surprising, this is a very secure site to say the least.

It would be easy to request a security token via ajax/php before leaving ClientWebsite (i would provide code to sys admin to put in ClientWebsite). This method would use hard coded credentials in the php script, return/append the token to the link so it's available when arriving at my js app. The js app would then check token's validity, and if OK, the login is suppressed on js app.

**problem:**

Someone could c/p the ajax call from ClientWebsite, run it outside of ClientWebsite, obtain a token, pass token to someone else who could use it to access my js app.

**question:**

I'd like to check for referrer in the php script, then issue token if referrer matches ClientWebsite, but no referrer is being sent & referrer can be spoofed anyway. What other method could I use to determine the request for a token is actually coming from ClientWebsite page?

Thanks!!

**edit:**

supply sys admin with ajax call like so:

```
$('#jsAppLink').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var currentHref = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        "type":"post",
        "dataType": "jsonp",
        "url": "https://mydomain.com/getTokenUsingCurl.php",
        "success": function (returnData){
            newHref = currentHref + "?token=" + returnData.token;
            window.location = newHref;
        }
    })
})
```

onClick, a php script on my server is queried. This script contains hard coded creds. out of public view. Return token to ClientWebsite, append it to js app url, then continue with link click routing user to js app.

Comment: Seems like you are doing all of this when there are so many methods of accomplishing a much more secure login. Why not looking into Secure Web Services, SSL/TLS, etc?

Comment: HTTP referrer is not a reliable value. It's a value sent from the client, so it could be easily faked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two layers of defense that you need to prevent this style of attack.

The first is to use SSL to prevent attackers off-system from intercepting the transmission and getting the token. It sounds like you may already doing this potentially (referrers are always blank from SSL enabled pages).

The second is to introduce a randomizing component (to differentiate requests from each other) and an identifying component (to identify the user) to the token.

So, what you can do is have the ClientWebsite issue a back-channel request to your server for the token. In this request, it should include the remote IP of the user, and you should validate that this request is only coming from the ClientWebsite's servers.

Then, instead of you returning the token directly, encrypt it using a random nonce. Then associate the nonce in your database with the provided remote IP of the user.

Now, when the browser makes a request to your site, it passes the encrypted token. You then lookup the key from the remote IP of the user (REMOTE_ADDR) and decrypt it.

It prevents replay attacks, since it would require IP spoofing to be able to do so. But be careful that if proxies are involved, it will significantly complicate things (and the proxy will be trusted instead of the user).

This is fairly reminiscent to how oauth1 works, except the orientation of trust is reversed (the Client Server is the auth source of record, where in oauth the authentication server is the auth source)...

```
/---------\            /---------------\           /-------------\
| Browser | ---------> | ClientWebsite |    IP     | Your Server |
|         |            |    Server     | --------> |             |
|         |            |               | Encrypted |             |
|         |            |               |   Token   |             |
|         |            |               | <-------- |             |
|         |  Encrypted |               |           |             |
|         |    Token   |               |           |             |
|         | <--------- |               |           |             |
|         |            \---------------/           |             |
|         |                                        |             |
|         |             Encrypted Token            |             |
|         | -------------------------------------> |             |
|         |                                        |             |
|         |             Session Start              |             |
|         | <------------------------------------- |             |
\---------/                                        \-------------/
```

It's secure because the only way to generate the encrypted token (encrypted with a strong random key, that never leaves the server) is to make the request from the ClientWebsite's server (because you're verifying that request came from the server directly, via a back-channel).

Comment: that would explain the blank referrer...ssl, thanks!!

Comment: looks like some server side code has to run on sys admin's servers or this won't work.

Comment: @dan: correct. That's the only way to do this securely. You're leveraging the trust the sys admin's server has with the user to back your trust in the user. Without running code on the admins server, you can't have this level of trust...

Comment: thanks again. this is further complicated by the fact that ClientWebsite is a sharepoint page, and I know 0.00 about sharepoint, asp.net, ect... ugh.

Comment: i'm almost complete with a proof of concept; having problems with encrypted token, it's too long once it arrives back at the browser to be a url parameter. I really don't want to post to my server from browser

Comment: how about storing the token in db, associate it with remote IP of user and random string. Pass random string back to browser, & use that as url parameter. Then when the user arrives at my app, use random string and remote Ip to lookup the token?

Comment: @dan: that should work ok...

Answer (score 0):

Having the ClientWebsite pass you a security token is probably the right idea (definitely avoid referrer). I think the key piece you're missing is ensuring that the token is *always changing*. The token should not only be comprised of preset credentials, but also with a variable element (timestamp if nothing else), and be short-lived.

When the ClientWebsite first sends a user to your app, you validate the token and ensure that it is very recent (ideally within a few seconds). If someone copies the token from the ajax call and passes it along to someone else, you need to be sure that it's no longer considered a valid token.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. I did not dev. the token system, here is the reference page: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/

Comment: You said that you "would provide code to sys admin to put in ClientWebsite" with "hard coded credentials in the php script." Sure sounds like you control that piece? That's the one where you want it variable, before it comes to your js app.

Comment: sorry about that, just found out ajax doesn't work cross domain. Ugh...

Comment: No it doesn't. You'll want the ClientWebsite to redirect to your app and pass the token in the URL (or POST ii).

Comment: edit above, think this would work?

Comment: I think that's the right idea, yes. Assuming getTokenUsingCurl.php is sitting on the _sysadmin's_ server. It needs to verify of course that the current user is allowed a token (don't let unauthenticated users just hit that url directly if they aren't supposed to), generate something nice and secure, timestamped, and only use for initial authentication (not ongoing access on every page load) on your end.

Comment: that's the problem... the .php is on my server

Comment: If you want the ClientWebsite to send you a secure token, then _something_ on the ClientWebsite has to generate it! You can't generate your own token. =)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27660/discussion-between-dan-and-jszobody)